# How to get a user id by searching the user's full name in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, search, built-in

I am making a search box, when a "first name or full name" is entered the result is a table listing the user_id, email, full name etc...

There can be more than one user with same "first name or full name" which in that cause I will need to loop through the result set.

The search also need to be flexible so that John Smith or John Smi or John will work.

e.g
[firstname lastname] [search]

Is there a way in WordPress to do this or do I have to use MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

This is what I needed

```
$search_name = 'John Smith';
$name_array = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $search_name);
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'first_name',
            'value' => $name_array[0],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'last_name',
            'value' => $name_array[1],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
        ));
$users_found = $users->get_results();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're writing your own search function, you need to use [Wp_User_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query). You'll find a lot of examples in that page, but what you need is probably the most basic form, like this:

```
$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'search'         => '*'.esc_attr( $your_search_string ).'*',
    'search_columns' => array(
        'user_login',
        'user_nicename',
        'user_email',
        'user_url',
    ),
) );
$users_found = $users->get_results();
```

However, if you want only to search for user in your backend, then you may use a plugin, there are many out there. [This one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/improved-user-search-in-backend/) works pretty well for what you need